# STHTTPRequest Multi Image upload

Tags: ios, iphone, connection, asihttprequest, sthttprequest

I'm changing the connection object of my app, untill yesterday I have used `AsiHttpRequest`:

```
[request setData:imgDataBig withFileName:@"imagename" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"image"];
[request setData:imgDataThumb withFileName:@"thumbname" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"thumb"];
```

Now I'm using `SthttpRequest`, and to replicate the `AsiHttpRequest` I've tried this code:

```
[request setDataToUpload:imgDataThumb parameterName:@"thumb" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"thumbname"];
[request setDataToUpload:imgDataBig parameterName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"imagename"];
```

With `SthttpRequest` only one will be send, How I can do to replicate the multi image upload that I have already done in `AsiHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, i have to download the last version of SthttpRequest, in last version i've found a new method for multiple uploads:

[request addDataToUpload:imgDataThumb parameterName:@"thumb" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"thumbname"];
[request addDataToUpload:imgDataBig parameterName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"imagename"];